# function that takes any type, but doesn't wipe out the shape information of the argument

Tags: typescript

How can I write a function that can take any type as argument and preserves the type info of the argument ?

```
const shouldPreserveShapeInfo = (t: any) => t // put any because I want it to work with any shape

const input = {
  foo: 'bar',
  john:'doe'
}

const result = shouldPreserveShapeInfo(input)
// result is now of type any and lost the shape information of input
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
const shouldPreserveShapeInfo = <T>(t: T) => t;

const input = {
  foo: 'bar',
  john:'doe'
}

const result = shouldPreserveShapeInfo(input)
// result is of type { foo: string, john: string }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWICuAbAJgBQE4FMI6wDccBleAQwAccBJMAMxBgF4YAeAFQD4AKKALhgcAlCy4woAbgBQ00JFgBLMJSSxWAb2kwYjEIIDkAI3JYDAGm0wAViHhhDaEDgPSAvrPnQYuCKnVwiKiYvgTEZFS0DCA8yqpQwkA)